# Semantic UI jquery functions doesn't work on Angular2 application

Tags: jquery, angular, semantic-ui

Even thought jquery is not limited in angular2 application, and you can truly use it in some cases such as needing to including some classy FrontEnd frameworks whose functionality relies on jquery. In my problem I am including Semantic UI for my angular2 application. Im not following the Angular Integration since it is on development stage and for some reason you can run jquery in angular2 application so i guess you can go with the traditional installation and integration.

However when implementing a sticky ui, I encounter some functionality errors of semantic ui. e.g.

```
$('.ui.sticky').sticky();
```

Typescript wont allow the sticky() function yielding this error:

```
Property 'sticky' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.
```

I installed jquery by this step

```
$ npm install jquery --save
$ npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
```

I included both the semantic ui and jquery dependencies on my angular-cli styles and scripts sections like this:

```
    "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "assets/default/momentum.css",
        "assets/semantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.css",
        "assets/semantic-ui/dist/components/icon.css",
        "assets/semantic-ui/dist/components/card.min.css",
        "assets/semantic-ui/dist/components/grid.min.css",
        "assets/semantic-ui/dist/components/sticky.min.css"
    ],
    "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "assets/semantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.js",
        "assets/semantic-ui/dist/components/sticky.min.js"
    ],
```

and call it in the angular application component

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'
```

**It was no use at all. Here is what i did in every tries. Component in different approach and tries with error:**

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as $ from 'jquery'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent  {
  title = 'Momentum';

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
     // The .sticky() has an error wrap: 
     // Property 'sticky' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.
     $('#header-panel').sticky()
  }

}
```

---

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var $:any

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent  {
  title = 'Momentum';

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // I got a run time error: ERROR ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    $('#header-panel').sticky()
  }

}
```

---

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as $ from 'jquery' 

interface JQuery{
  sticky(): void
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent  {
  title = 'Momentum';

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // Still the .sticky() has an error wrap: 
    // Property 'sticky' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.
    $('#header-panel').sticky()
  }

}
```

---

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as $ from 'jquery'

declare global {
  interface JQuery {
    sticky(): void
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Momentum';

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // On run time got this error: 
    // ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_jquery__(...).sticky is not a function
    $('#header-panel').sticky()
  }

}
```

---

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as $ from 'jquery'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Momentum';

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // No matter what still got an
    // ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_jquery__(...).sticky is not a function
    (<any> $('#header-panel')).sticky()
    ($('#header-panel') as any).sticky()
  }

}
```

It doesn't really work, It drives me nut shall i give up? or there is still some solution?

Comment: declare var $:any ,$('something').something() ...gives you error ??

Comment: declare var $:any gives me `ReferenceError: $ is not defined``

Comment: just completed developing a website with angular and semantic,declare var $:any worked for me

Comment: how did you include the jquery dependency?

Comment: understood,i followed the same method

Comment: yes, but declare var $:any doesnt work for me some how i dont understand since i include the jquery on scripts section in angular-cli.json

Comment: you are doing declare var $:any in component right ? and in the global declaration ,not inside the component right ?

Comment: im doing declare var $:any inside a component and the declare global {} declaration is in the same component

Comment: can you post whole component code please including import section

Comment: just a moment please

Comment: @VikhyathMaiya please look at my updated question. its a bit longer though but it is the same component in different tries with error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153323/discussion-between-vikhyath-maiya-and-shift-n-tab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the discussion we had in chats,i realized that there are two problems in the way you are trying to make it work
1.Including both jquery and jquery types(not sure why this doesnt work)
2.The way you are including the semantic ui files in your project
Follow following steps to make it work

1. 1.ng new newProjectname
2. 2.npm install jquery
3. download semantic from
   https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-CSS/archive/master.zip
   and extract the folder into your project
4. .Give the reference to semantic ui and jquery in
   angular cli as

   `"scripts": [
               "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
               "your-ui-folder-path/semantic.min.js"
             ],
             "styles": [
             "styles.css",
             "your-ui-folder-path/semantic.min.css"
             ],`
5. Now you can use jquery in the project as

   declare var $:any;
6. And refer to functions as

   $('id or class').dropdown();//any function

Hope this helps.If this doesnt work,please refer to the answer suggested by Saad

Answer (score 4):

Well ,since you've tried **including the dependencies** way and didn't worked out for you , i suggest using this simple trick like the following :

[[WORKING DEMO]](http://plnkr.co/edit/BydMHk?p=preview) *(Scroll down to see sticky behavior)*

1- Simply include Semantic-UI in `index.html` file :

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.11/semantic.min.js"></script>
<!--or -->
    <script src="relaive_path_to/semantic.min.js"></script>
```

2- Simply include jQuery in `index.html` file (same way as semantic-ui):

3- In `your.component.ts` file add this:`declare var $: any;` next to the importing section , then initialize the component ) in `ngAfterViewInit(){}` like the following :

**component.ts**

```
import {Component,OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
declare var $: any;
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'demo.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 

    ngAfterViewInit(){

          $('.ui.sticky').sticky();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. There is an issue about it on GitHub, where people propose to just include jQuery through tag script in an HTML file. This approach was not good for my situation.
I've included jQuery in my app.module.ts and made it available globally through window object.

```
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
(<any> window)['jQuery'] = jQuery;
```

It's not a good approach of work with imported libraries, but if semantic ui works by such way, that's what can we only do.